# By bus - by a big bus

Tags: articles

**The children traveled by bus.** - correct

**The children traveled by a big bus.**

Is it correct? Or should it be "on a big bus"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "big" is a red herring here.  The important word is "a".

When you say "by bus" you are referring to the bus system.  It actually doesn't say how many bus vehicles they used, it is quite possible that they had to change busses to complete their journey.

If you say "a bus" you mean a single vehicle, and the idiom is "on a bus".

Further qualifying that the bus is "big" doesn't fundamentally change that idiom.

However "by" is also completely understandable and probably would also be used from time to time by native speakers.

Answer (score 2):

*By bus* indicates the mode of transport rather than the particular vehicle. If you want to describe the bus itself, say *on/in a big bus.*